# Maximum likelihood - First order conditions bivariate Normal

Tags: generalized-least-squares

I am trying to estimate the first order conditions from the following:

p1,p2~N(mu1,mu2,sigma1,sigma2,sigma12)
In addition, another variable total_cost=p1*x1+p2*x2+noise
If I observe x1,x2, and tot_cost, how do I estimate sigma1,sigma2, and sigma12 using maximum likelihood? I hope to get the first order conditions.

Comment: Welcome to CV! Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users.  Since this looks like homework (apologies if it's not), please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing. If this is self-study rather than homework, let us know, and... it's still a good idea to show us what you've tried.   And use Mathjax!

Comment: This is not homework! I need it for my research.